# How do I get the home directory of an *arbitrary* (i.e. not the current) user in PHP under Windows?

Tags: php, windows, shell

Is there any way to get the home directory of a user specified by username in PHP under Windows?

I know how to get the home directory of the *current* user (via the HOMEDRIVE, HOMEPATH, and HOMESHARE environment variables). But what about for an arbitrary user when you only know the username?

In other words, what's the equivalent to something like `~username` under Windows?

Comment: It's it always <DISK_LETTER>:/Users/<USERNAME>?

Comment: @VladimirHraban Unfortunately it's completely configurable. User home directories don't necessarily reside in the same folder, the same drive, or even the same physical machine.

Comment: I don't have a windows machine here but maybe registry node HKEY_Users\<their SID> \Environment\Tmp will be of any help. There are ways to read/write to the registry using php & Wscript

Comment: @VladimirHraban: the user registry hives are only loaded when the corresponding user is logged in.

Comment: There isn't really a close equivalent of `~username` under Windows.  Even the information in HOMEDRIVE/HOMEPATH/HOMESHARE isn't consistent; it may point to either a local profile folder or a network home directory, and the two have little in common.  So you really need to know which folder you're actually after.  Unfortunately, however, the answer is probably "there's no way to do that" no matter which folder you want.  (One exception: if you know the user has a network home directory, this information is available from the domain.)

Comment: (It is likely that whatever you're actually trying to do, this isn't the best way to do it.  We may be able to suggest alternatives if you can describe your scenario.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm trying to emulate `~username` under Windows in a PHP library dedicated to path manipulation. You can check out the project [here](https://github.com/eloquent/pathogen) and the relevant issue [here](https://github.com/eloquent/pathogen/issues/33) for more info.

Comment: I think the only possible answer to that is "no can do"; firstly because `~username` has a semantic meaning that simply doesn't exist in Windows, secondly because even in the simplest case there's no way to look up the location of a user profile or any of the user's folders without having a security token for the user (to get which you either need the user's password, or an existing process running in the user's context), and lastly because if the folder is on the network you probably won't have access to it even if you could find it.

Comment: You could, I suppose, take the Cygwin approach and create a directory tree yourself: map `~username` to `c:\homes\username`.  That might or might not be useful, depending on how you anticipate that the library will be used.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I think that would probably do more harm than good. If it's not possible to do it "properly", I'd rather throw an exception under Windows. I fear you may be right about there being no way to achieve what I want.

Comment: Also, FYI, this is how Python handles it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser - seems like a filthy hack, really. So if Python can't do it, that's probably a good indication that it can't be done I guess.

Comment: If the Python documentation means what I think it means, then, yeah, that's unreliable: the profile folder (even ignoring the other issues) does not always have the same name as the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only possible answer to that is "no can do", for the following reasons:

- `~username` has a semantic meaning that simply doesn't exist in Windows; there is no single "home" directory, but rather various distinct directories for specific purposes.  Many of these can be relocated either by the system administrator or by the end user, and may be subject to localization in non-English configs.

  (In particular, note that even when dealing with the current user there are very few circumstances in which putting a file in the user's profile directory, or in any fixed path relative to that directory, is sensible.  For example, some applications write to `<userprofile>\Documents` or to `<userprofile>\AppData` and as a result misbehave if the folder in question has a localized name or has been redirected or relocated.)
- Even in the simplest case there's no way to look up the location of a user profile or any of the user's folders without having a security token for the user, to get which you either need the user's password or an existing process running in the user's context.  (That's a white lie: actually, if you have admin privilege it *is* possible to fake a token, but the effort would be disproportionate and it isn't clear that a faked token would work reliably in this context anyway.)
- If the folder is on the network you probably won't have access to it even if you could find it.

In specific circumstances there may be approaches that would make sense, such as creating your own directory tree or requiring that each account have a legacy ("net user" or NT domain style) home directory configured.  For a generic library, this probably isn't a good idea, though if you thought it was worth it you could provide a function allowing the programmer to explicitly turn this behaviour on (perhaps with a configurable directory root, for example).

With regards to your comment about throwing an exception: keep in mind that in Windows `~` is a legitimate character which could occur at the beginning of an actual file name or relative path.  So, depending on context, it might be preferable to give it no special meaning at all.

Comment: I think you're right about the majority of it. I would argue that the environment variables `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` constitute the single "home" directory that is semantically equivalent to `~` under most *nix environments. But this obviously only holds true for the current user. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If a legacy home directory is configured (one shown by "net user") then `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` point to it.  Such a directory typically points to a network folder (though it can be local) where the user is expected to store files, i.e., it has approximately the same meaning as the user's Documents folder.  If the Documents folder is redirected by group policy, this will probably be to the same location as the legacy home directory.

Comment: In contrast, if a legacy home directory is *not* configured, `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` point not to the user's Documents folder but to their profile folder, which (as already discussed) is almost never useful information.  So to sum up, the reason I don't consider this equivalent to the Linux `~` is because the result is inconsistent, and in the more common scenario is of little use.  (It is unfortunate that the default is not to point to the user's Documents folder.  That would have made it much more useful.)

Comment: I see the most common use case being storage of configuration files on a per-user basis (ala `~/.ssh`). So long as the directory is typically writable by the current user, and remains consistent *for each user*, it's good enough for that purpose.

Comment: That's not too unreasonable, though personally I find it annoying when software drops configuration files in my home directory.  That's for *my* files; configuration files are supposed to go in the Application Data folder.   Granted, MS software has a nasty habit of creating folders in your home directory without asking... that's annoying too. :-)  (Do make sure you avoid putting large files in the user's profile directory, because if a roaming profile is configured all those files have be copied over the network at logon and logoff.)